# TCP handshake process

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I have TCP client application and trying to connect with Server located at remote machine.
I am able to connect it.

when I Send Message Called Hello packet the Server should respond with data and time info.
but to my surprise recv returns 0 at client.
since I can't Debug code at Server.
I am not sure but may be there is problem in encoding the message format hello packet at th client upon receiving the wrong packet server is clsoing  the connection
I wanted to confirm the meaning of following sequence  is

**I got following info from wire shark**

```
   src IP------>dst ip SYN
   dst ip ----->src ip SYN,ACK
   src IP------>dst ip ACK


   src IP------>dst ip continuation or non http traffic "Hello Packet"
   dst ip------>ACK
   dst ip------>FIN, ACK
```

Does this means Server is closing the connection once it receives the hello packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the FIN,ACK sequence is sent by one of the entity connected when they want to close the connection